# Console.log a multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, console, console.log

So I have created a multi-dimensional array: (i.e. one with two sets of 'coordinates')

```
var items = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];
```

My site is in development and the array, when it is loaded, and what it contains is constantly changing, so I need to be able to, whilst running the script, dynamically view the contents of the array.

So, I use this:

```
console.log(items);
```

to output it to the console. This gives me the following output:

[image: alt: Unreadable output of my array]

So, is there any other way in which I can do the equivalent of `console.logging` my array, but with more *readable* output?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use javascript's [`console.table`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/table)

This will display your array in table form, making it much more readable and easy to analyse
It is quite a little known feature, however useful when you have a multi-dimentional array.

So, change your code to `console.table(items);`
It should give you something like this:

```
 -----------------------
|(index)|   0   |   1   |
|   0   |   1   |   2   |
|   1   |   3   |   4   |
|   2   |   5   |   6   |
 -----------------------
```

Answer (score 31):

You can use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
```

Its output will be like

> [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]

```js
var items = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];
console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
```

Comment: Thank you this does provide a clearer output, I just prefer the table method. +1 for the nice method though :)